# If two subsets of a metric space are equal, they have the same limit points $A=B \implies A'=B'$

Tags: metric-spaces

I imagine this is true by definition, but I don't know how to prove it: If two subsets of a metric space are equal, they have the same limit points. E.g:

$A=B \implies A'=B'$

Notation: $Q'$ is the set of all limit points of $Q$.

---

> **Just motivation for the question**: Not a PSQ btw. The motivation is to be able to solve a harder question from Rudin(But this **isn't** my question here):
>
> $$B_n = \cup_{i=1}^n A_n \implies \bar{B_n}=\cup_{i=1}^n \bar{A_n}$$

Comment: If $x$  is a limit point of $A$ then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $A$ converging to $x.$ But $A=B.$ So the sequence is also from $B.$ Hence $x$ is a limit point of $B$ also. Similarly the other way round.

Comment: I'll be afk for 30 min, something just came up

Comment: @Krish That was exactly my thought, but I didn't know how to make it rigorous, thanks I'll see what I can do with that when I come back

Comment: But if two sets are equal, then there is only one set, isn't it?

Comment: It’s the meaning of “$=$” that’s tripping you up. If $A=B$, then $A$ *is* $B$. There’s nothing to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:for two sets
 $$A\cup B\subset \overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\Rightarrow\overline{A\cup B}\subset \overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$$
Also $$ B\subset A\cup B\Rightarrow  \overline B\subset \overline{A\cup B}$$
Similarly $$ A\subset A\cup B\Rightarrow  \overline A\subset \overline{A\cup B}$$
So $$ \overline A\cup\overline B\subset \overline{A\cup B}$$
Therefore  $$ \overline A\cup\overline B= \overline{A\cup B}$$